# Define differentiable Custom loss function TF2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

Below is my network compile statement, which is running fine in TF2.0

```
    model.compile(
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=adam, metrics=[accuracy]
    )
```

Instead of standard loss function, I wanted to pass custom loss function with below logic.

Outside Data frame(df) is:
[image]

Our main training class is class_2.

**Custom loss function logic is below**

```
if y and y_pred is not same, 
Loss = 1 if 4-digit class_1 code doesn’t match.
Loss = 0.5 if 4 digit class_1 code matches but 5th/6th digit class_1 code doesn't match.
Loss = 0.25 if 5th/6th digit class_1 code matches.
```

```
def custom_loss_function(y, y_hat):
    y_true = K.cast(tf.reshape(y, [-1]), y_hat.dtype)
    y_pred = K.cast(K.argmax(K.cast(y_hat, y_true.dtype)), y_true.dtype)
    if str(y) != str(y_hat):
        lv1 = df['class_1'][df.class_2 == y].values[0]
        lv1_hat = df['class_1'][df.class_2 == y_hat].values[0]
        if lv1 == lv1_hat:
            loss = 0.25
        else:
            if lv1[:4] != lv1_hat[:4]:
                loss = 1
            elif lv1[:4] == lv1_hat[:4] and lv1[4:] != lv1_hat[4:]:
                loss = 0.5
    else:
        loss = 0
    return loss
```

Can you please tell me where I am loosing to build custom loss function which is differentiable.

getting y and y_pred display like below:

```
Epoch 1/15
y actual: Tensor("custom_loss_function/Cast:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32): y_preds: Tensor("custom_loss_function/Cast_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
y=Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=int64) and y_hat = Tensor("functional_1/dense/Softmax:0", shape=(None, 7969), dtype=float32)
```

I am getting error like below:

```
StagingError: in user code:

    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-15-a959fba13b37>:9 custom_loss_function  *
        lv1 = df['class_1'][df.class_2 == y].values[0]

    IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

**Please help me on this.**

Comment: The value for `y` is not matching anything in your dataframe, and you get an empty array. Without more details, I can't help you more than that.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I added y and y_pred display in question. If not, please write one sample function with constant values for me which is workable.